# Custom Docker resource limits

Tags: virtual-memory, docker

I'm using Docker desktop on Monterey, on an M1 Mac.

Some commands in an Ubuntu-based container are running out of memory and getting killed by the system. I opened a second terminal window and launched `top`, and I can see the container running out of memory, then out of swap, and then the command gets killed.

I've already maxed out the Docker desktop settings at 16GB RAM and 4GB of swap. I'm happy to give it more swap space but the sliders don't go any farther to the right. Is there any way to let it use more of either of these?

Additional: It seems like the limits in Docker desktop override command-line args. Attempting different limits, like `docker run --rm -it --platform linux/amd64 --memory-swap 32G --memory 16G ubuntu`, has no effect on the limits the container actually gets.